# LateInitializationError: Field 'dropdownvalue' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having this issue :

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════

LateInitializationError: Field 'dropdownvalue' has not been initialized.
```

This error is caused by a `dropdown` being `null` where the values are being fetched from database.

My code is this :

```
late List? Clients= []; // Dropdown list containing values from database.
late String? dropdownvalue; // The choosen value.
```

Everytime I load the screen , I'm getting a red screen showing an error then the screen renders fine.

How can I prevent this error from showing ?

Comment: if you are using late with variable then you have to initiliaze before using that variable.when you pass dropdownvalue to dropdown widget it expects for value for initial stuff

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this :

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchClients().whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

and removing the `late` for every variable.